# Adding a well discernible symbol on top of a heat map in QGIS without duplicating a point layer

Tags: qgis-3, heat-map, ux

I have a point layer in QGIS 3.14 on which I applied a heat map symbology:

[image: heatmap points]

I would like to add a well defined / discernible shape (circles here) on top of the heatmap for the underlying points to actually make the points discernible for the user. This would help him to select the points on a web app based on this QGIS project file, because when I select to "Weight points by" an intensity attribute, the heatmap blends with the basemap layer and some spots may be really hard to see where the intensity values are low as shown for 4 dots on this second picture:

[image: heatmap as function of intensity attribute]

Is this possible without having to actually duplicate the layer?

For the moment, the only workaround I found, as you can see in the layer window, is to duplicate the layer with simple circles symbols on top of the heatmap.

Comment: Just to understand better your point: why do you want to avoid duplicating the layer? You don't copy any data, you just duplicate the symbolization.